# Is there anyway to list existing routes in FeathersJS framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, feathersjs

In Laravel i can use

`php artisan route list`

To see all routes in my **Laravel** project .. I am asking for the *same behavior* but in **FeathersJS** framework which built on top of ExpressJS.

If not, is there anyway to create that as a custom command using node js to obtain the same behavior ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is just a list of all folders in `src/services` but you can also get a dynamic list as shown in the [documentation for app.services](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#services). This can be quickly turned into a command like this:

```js
// list-services.js
const app = require('./src/app');
const serviceList = Object.keys(app.services);

console.log(serviceList.join('\n');
```

Now you can run this with `node list-services`

Comment: if you have a lot of services or dynamic ones the directory trick is usually not enough (and doesn't always communicate the names on which they were registered...)